# How do I get rid of these leading spaces that are causing simple multiplication to fail?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table listing plants, quantities, and prices. Somehow most of the prices have some leading spaces which, I assume, are causing the #VALUE error when I try to apply a markup multiplier.

I've tried Trim, Trim(Clean), copy/paste special, find/replace, but nothing works - at the end I still have numbers with leading spaces.

I even exported to csv and then imported back into excel with the idea that there was some kind of formatting causing trouble.

What the heck? And is there some way I can post a section of my sheet for review?

> [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Please copy paste some the actual data in your question so we can test.

Comment: When I try to paste it seems to want to drop it in as an image.

Comment: What is the formula you are trying to use?

Comment: Why not just format the cells as number?

Comment: I tried formatting as number, as text, as general. Nothing worked.

Comment: @ScottCraner the formula is simply =c2*2.5

Comment: hard to tell from a picture but try: `=TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,CHAR(160),"")))*2.5`

Comment: as the formula in the final column?

Comment: @ScottCraner Sweet Baby Jesus! That did it. So what does the Stubstitute function do here...

Comment: also, put it in an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Char(160) is non breaking space, so he is replacing every instance of non-breaking space with a plain space character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different type of spaces(Non-Breaking Space) in your numbers.  These usually are `CHAR(160)`. Neither TRIM not CLEAN will remove these as Excel sees them as valid characters.  But that makes the "numbers" text string and as such cannot be multiplied.

So we use SUBSTITUTE to remove those characters and throw in TRIM and CLEAN for good measure:

```
=TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,CHAR(160),"")))*2.5
```

Answer (score 3):

You might run into a ton of "**non-breaking spaces**" that are not handled by `CLEAN()`. This is very common when taking data from web pages as they, like PDF's, are concerned only with the visual presentation, not someone scraping data for further use. But it comes a ton from programs outputting data especially when they don't picture general use of the data, but rather a limited set of people using it. Or did 28 years ago when the CSV output functionality was written, never to be updated.

The problem is easier to handle in your spreadsheet since you literally only want the numerical portion with nothing that is not a numerical digit.

If you needed to preserve indicators of the value being negative, that'd be tougher. Or characters that were anything but these spaces. Or, like me, get strings that need the output to be discrete numbers. In a string like "90.02 45.55 .062" but preserved so they could be extracted.

However, you simply need the digits in a single string and considered numbers by Excel. The following formula does that:

```
=VALUE(TEXTJOIN(,TRUE,IFERROR(MID(C1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(C1)),1)*1,"")))
```

It uses `SEQUENCE()` to get a series of values that rises by 1 and is as long as your target's length. Then it uses those to specify the start spot for the `MID()` function which outputs a matrix of the characters in the target. It then does a math operation (`*1`) on that which works for the digits in the matrix, but gives errors for anything not a digit (0-9). `IFERROR()` converts that string to digits with "" anywhere the errors popped up (anywhere the target did NOT have a digit). `TEXTJOIN()` then converts that matrix into a simple output string, ignoring those "" elements so you now have a useful string of just the digits that existed in the target. It is regarded as text and will display so.

At this moment, the formula is useful for you if you have a reasonably recent version of Excel. That is because Excel will recognize a string of digits, even if formatted as text (they're only formatted, not changed in some fundamental way after all), as just that, digits, if presented to a function that REQUIRES, or reasonably expects, only numerical data as its input. So "C1+1" even will regard that text as a number and do teh addition rather than give an error or give you 0+1=1. **HOWEVER,** not all functions will treat the output this way. `VLOOKUP()` will treat it as whatever it seems to be, text in this case, and looking in a table of numbers find no match, giving you an error. So I wrapped the above in `VALUE()` for a finish so that the result is considered a number and if you use the result as input for a lookup function, as it seems someone else might, it would work.

So YOU could drop that function from it and it would still do the markup multiplication as desired.

However, if you do not have the new `SPILL` functions, or especially if you have a pretty old version of Excel, the following formula will work in basically all versions of Excel for Windows and will always produce a numerical output:

```
{=ROUND(NPV(-0.9,0,IFERROR(MID(L1,LEN(C1)-ROW(INDIRECT("C1:I"&LEN(C1)))+1,1)/100,"")),3)}
```

Note that it is a **CSE** formula. Used as a regular formula, it strips the last two digits, sometimes... and the output is formatted as currency. (Excel's helpful... 'cause `NPV()` is a financial function you MUST want it formatted as currency, right?)

The above formula is from "somewhere on the internet somewhen pretty long ago"... I wish I could credit my source for it but I do not remember the source. Apologies to some helpful guru.

Glad you asked this becuase I have that in plenty of places and needed to update for how `SEQUENCE()` can help one. Not to mention replacing the change from internal matrix in the function to the useful string that is output with `TEXTJOIN()` since that's available now too! Immediate benefit! It's a wonderful thing!